# Exibir controle em Partial View condicionalmente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Preciso que um controle de uma *Partial View* seja exibido de acordo com uma condição. Para algumas *views* um botão apareceria para outras não e isso seria definido através de um parâmetro na chamada da *Partial View*.

Depois de pesquisar vi que posso usar `ViewDataDictionary`, porém ao tentar implementar não obtive sucesso.

Para que o controle fosse exibido na *View* a chama seria da seguinte forma:

```
 @Html.Partial("_smart_actions", item, new ViewDataDictionary {{ "MenuClone", true }})
```

Para que o controle **não** fosse exibido na *View* a chama seria da seguinte forma:

```
 @Html.Partial("_smart_actions", item)
```

*Partial View*:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = Model.Id })" class="link-mutted" title="Visualizar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
|
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = Model.Id })" class="link-mutted" title="Editar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
|
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = Model.Id })" class="link-mutted" title="Excluir">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
@if (ViewDataDictionary == true)
{
<a href="@Url.Action("DuplicarDados")" class="link-mutted" title="Duplicar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
}
```

Simplesmente não aparace o controle, como contornar este problema?

Comment: Não entendi qual seria a condição pra *Partial* aparecer. Poderia explicar melhor esta parte?

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez Vou editar a pergunta para ser mais clara.

Comment: E ai @Jota, tudo bem? Se puder colocar a condição para que a partial apareça, ajudaria. Tipo, permissão de usuário, url, etc.
Da forma que está, está meio confuso.

Comment: @Randrade Beleza brother! Não teria condição, pois esta _Partial view_ seria usada em todas _views_. Só que em alguns casos o controle Clonar irá aparecer em outras não. Então queria colocar um parâmetro na chamda da _partial_ de forma que pudesse reutilizar em todo o projeto. Mas consegui resolver. Claro que aceito que aceito sugestões para melhorar a solução encontrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de alguns teste consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma.

Na *View* chamo a *Partial View* com um parâmetro que define se o controle será ou não exibido.

Para exibir:

```
 @Html.Partial("_smart_actions", item, new ViewDataDictionary {{ "MenuClone", true }})
```

Para  **não** exibir:

```
 @Html.Partial("_smart_actions", item)
```

Na *Partial View* faço o teste assim:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = Model.Id })" class="link-mutted" title="Visualizar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
|
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = Model.Id })" class="link-mutted" title="Editar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
|
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = Model.Id })" class="link-mutted" title="Excluir">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
@if (ViewData["MenuClone"] != null && ViewData["MenuClone"].Equals(true))
{
    <text>
        |
        <a href="@Url.Action("Clonar")" class="link-mutted" title="Clonar">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </text>
}
```

Isto me permite ter um única *Partial View* que pode ser reutilizada em todo o projeto e exibe seu conteúdo de acordo com a condição passada pela *View* que vai usá-la.

Comment: Esta solução não é boa porque quem deveria controlar a apresentação ou não da *Partial* é a *View* que chama a *Partial*. Vou propôr uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é que o controle dessa *Partial* seja feito pela *View* que chama esta *Partial*:

```
@if (condicao) {
    @Html.Partial("_smart_actions", item)
}
```

Isto se deve ao fato de que sua *Partial* dependerá sempre de um `ViewDataDictionary` para ser usada. Como o princípio das *Partials* é o reuso delas, usar o `ViewDataDictionary` obrigatoriamente vai contra o padrão de design geral da aplicação.

Comment: No caso a _partial_ seria os botões de operação de registro (visualizar, editar e excluir) que apareceria em todas as _INDEX.CSHTNL_. Só que em alguns casos além dos botões relacionados acima será exibido o botão "clonar". Então para facilitar o reaproveitamento achei que seria mais fácil na chamada da _partial_ dentro da view passar ou não um parâmetro que define se o botão deverá ou não ser exibido. Se for para ser exibido é só deixa `ViewDataDictionary`null. Por isso o teste na _partial_. Agora se vai contra o padrão de design é um caso  a ser analisado. Agradeço.